# xampp linking js file by included file

Tags: javascript, php, html, apache, xampp

i linked my js file in a file called footer.php and included it in the home file, when i run the home file the script doesn't work

The home file

```
<?php include 'inc/header.php'; ?>
    <header id="index-header">

    </header>
<?php include 'inc/footer.php'; ?>
```

The footer file

```
        <script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/myScript.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should make these changes in your **footer.php** file

```
<?php

 echo '<script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
       <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
       <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
       <script src="js/myScript.js"></script>
     </body>
   </html>';

/* If this code doesn't work then use below code */
/** echo '<script src="./js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
       <script src="./js/popper.min.js"></script>
       <script src="./js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
       <script src="./js/myScript.js"></script>
     </body>
   </html>';
**/


?>
```

But do you think what you are doing is right? You should put **HTML** and **BODY** tags in the `home` file instead of in the `header` and `footer` file.

**example:**

**Home.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- code -->
    <!-- or -->
    <?php include 'inc/header.php'; ?>
  </head>
  <body>

    <header id="index-header">
       <!-- code -->
    </header>

    <?php include 'inc/footer.php'; ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

**Footer.php**

```
<?php

 echo '<script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
       <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
       <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
       <script src="js/myScript.js"></script>';
?>
```

---

hope it will be helpful for you

Comment: thx for your reply but id doesn't work :(

Comment: @OsamaAmr can you explain what was the problem?